# VMware Windows 7 corrupted, need to recover my files

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware

I installed a Windows 7 operating system on VMware virtual machine and my host computer is running Windows 10. My Windows 7 operating system of virtual machine is corrupted and I need to recover some files.

Is there any way I can access my Windows 7 files and folders from my host operating system?

If there is any other solution to recover my files from the virtual machine Windows 7, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily mount (map) your virtual machine's disk in your host OS.

If you don't have VMware Workstation (which allows the following from the GUI), then:

1. Download and install [VMware Disk Mount Utility](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?productId=46&downloadGroup=WKST-550-DISK-MOUNT-UTL#product_downloads) from VMware.
2. Locate Windows 7 virtual machine's disk file (for example `D:\vmware\windows7.vmdk`).
3. Use the following command to mount the virtual machine disk at `Z:`

   ```
   vmware-mount Z: D:\vmware\windows7.vmdk
   ```
4. If you have snapshots, act accordingly to program instructions, ie. confirm that if you are aware how snapshots work.

Full documentation for this tool is available from VMware [here](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/VMwareDiskMount.pdf) (PDF).